# Can a LC tank circuit amplify frequencies beyond the bandwidth region?

Tags: amplifier, oscillator, resonance

The LC tank circuit in a class C amplifier has a specific resonating frequency of 1/(2piLC). Depending on the Q factor its frequency may vary inside its bandwidth.

Does this mean my class C amplifier can only amplify input signals with frequencies inside the bandwidth region?

I read that bandwidth is the region where the power is more than half of the power of the center resonating freqeuncy:
$$BW=f_2 - f_1$$

BUT it does not say it cannot accept frequencies outside this region. So can it accept frequencies outside the bandwidth?

Comment: You can apply whatever frequencies you want but, the further you are away from the natural resonant frequency, the lower will be the resulting amplitude.

Comment: Also an LC tank is made of **passive** components so **amplification** is not something that can happen. You cannot get more signal power out than you put in.

Comment: Yes, but not very effectively. This is a huge problem in RF receiver design because high level input signals near (but outside) the tuned circuit bandwidth break through (attenuated, but still louder than the signals you want) interfering with the wanted signal.